# How to limit linked entities in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

When using Entity Framework Core, we've got two linked entities, as a simplified example a course and a booking. A course has a list of bookings. The course also has a property for the number of allowed bookings (This can be different on each course). When inserting a record into the bookings table for a particular course we want to check that the count of bookings is less than the Allowed Bookings. What would be the best way to do this avoiding concurrency conflicts? Multiple people will be creating bookings at the same time.

I've tried using EF to run the select of the count before inserting but if two are inserting at the same time this can cause the bookings to exceed the limit.

I've thought about using a Date Modified column on the Course table and using that as a concurrency check and thereby updating that every time we add a booking but that would cause a concurrency error when the count may have gone from 4 to 5 and is still under the limit of 10, so should go through without any issue. It would also mean we're updating an extra table when really all we're interested in here is inserting the booking if possible.

--EDIT 1

Here's some code I'm trying. This is in the repository and is called from the controller. The problem with this is if multiple requests come in at once it can go over the limit of AvailableSpaces

```
public async Task<Models.Booking> AddBooking(Models.Booking booking)
{
    var bookingEntity = _mapper.Map<Entities.Booking>(booking);

    var e = await _context.Events.Include(x => x.Bookings).FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == booking.EventId);

    if (e.AvailableSpaces > 0)
    {
        _context.Add(bookingEntity);
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return _mapper.Map<Models.Booking>(bookingEntity);
}
```

--EDIT 2

I've tried using a transaction but this still fails for some reason and goes above the AvailableSpaces limit. Surely this should lock the row until the transaction is committed?

```
public async Task<Models.Booking> AddBooking(Models.Booking booking)
{
    var bookingEntity = _mapper.Map<Entities.Booking>(booking);

    var strategy = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();

    await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
        {
            try
            {
                var e = await _context.Events.Include(x => x.Bookings).FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == booking.EventId);

                if (e.AvailableSpaces == 0)
                    throw new Exception("No free spaces");

                _context.Add(bookingEntity);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    });

    return _mapper.Map<Models.Booking>(bookingEntity);
}
```

--EDIT 3

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int TotalSpaces { get; set; }
    public int AvailableSpaces { get { return TotalSpaces - AllocatedSpaces; } }
    public int AllocatedSpaces { get { return Bookings?.Count ?? 0; } }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    public string CourseCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

--EDIT 4

Added AvailableSpaces to database and persist this through which enables the concurrency check on the event, but feel this should not be required as I can work this out from the bookings assigned to the event.

```
public async Task<Models.Booking> AddBooking(Models.Booking booking)
{
    if (booking == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(booking));

    var bookingEntity = _mapper.Map<Entities.Booking>(booking);

    bool saveFailed;

    var e = await _context.Events.Where(x => x.Bookings.Count < x.TotalSpaces).Include(x => x.Bookings).SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == bookingEntity.EventId);

    do
    {
        saveFailed = false;
        try
        {
            if (e == null || e.AvailableSpaces == 0)
                throw new Exception("No free spaces");

            e.Bookings.Add(bookingEntity);
            e.AvailableSpaces -= 1;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            saveFailed = true;
            Console.WriteLine($"Concurrency Exception for event id: {booking.EventId}");
            ex.Entries?.Single()?.Reload();
        }
    } while (saveFailed);

    return _mapper.Map<Models.Booking>(bookingEntity);
}
```

Also tried setting the AvailableSpaces by doing a count of the bookings but then it stops working for some reason and goes over the limit on multiple calls.

```
e.AvailableSpaces = e.TotalSpaces - (e.Bookings?.Count() ?? 0);
```

Comment: Can't you use a lock mechanism?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/semaphore-and-semaphoreslim

Comment: I was hoping there was something already built into Entity Framework Core which would help deal with this. I'm not entirely sure the link on threading could work here?

Comment: Where/When do you increment AvailableSpaces?

Comment: @GaryStewart I have added my entity model for the Event. AvailableSpaces is not persisted to the database as this is the Total Spaces (In db) minus the number of bookings in the db. if (e.AvailableSpaces == 0) could be written if ((e.TotalSpaces - (e.Bookings?.Count??0)) == 0)

Comment: You need to put a lock around the code that is reading and writing to the database.  The code creates a condition where the count could be evaluated as free space being evaluated by multiple threads for the same event.  I don't think that EF is going to handle this condition very well.

Comment: @GaryStewart Shouldn't the transaction in EDIT 2 be doing this? I think I'm not understanding something here as this isn't making sense. I updated the model to persist the AvailableSpaces to the database. If I do that and decrement this aat the same time as adding the booking that appears to work, due to the concurrency token on the event. I just feel this should be unnecessary to maintain this extra field. See Edit 4